# Verbal noun after a passive construction - dangling or not?

Tags: dangling-participles

Is this sentence correct (in a mathematical text):

"This formula is established by observing that A+B=C" ?

My feeling is that everything is OK because there IS identity of subjects: the reader who observes one formula can establish the other one.
In other words, the passive voice makes "this formula" a "fake" subject.

Comment: "is established by observing" is awkward.

Comment: *Dangling* doesn't come into this use: it's a gerund, not a participle, and it acts as object of the preposition *by*. "This formula is established by Fred" is the same construction.

Comment: @StoneyB Wouldn't you say that the whole clause, rather than the ---*ing* form, is the complement of the preposition?

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, indeed. "It is the head of the clause which is the object &c"

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing "fake" about the subject "This formula."  It's a perfectly valid subject of the passive verb "is established."  In the transposition from the active voice, the **subject** is ordinarily moved to the object of the preposition "*by*."  Thus your active-voice version might be

> The **reader** established this formula by observing that A+B=C.

In the passive, this becomes

> This formula is established (*by* the **reader**) by observing that A+B=C.

When the active-voice subject is unknown or unimportant, it is often elided, as indicated by the parenthesis.  This leaves the second "by" introducing an adverbial prepositional phrase of manner to modify the verb.  Perhaps you feel a small bit of unease at that "by" echoing the missing one.

A dangling modifier would be one that can only modify the missing active-voice subject:

> Having observed that A+B=C, the formula is established.